# Pytest - RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I am developing an application using FastAPI and implementing tests with Pytest. My goal is to apply **`parametrize`** to all tests, as well as to delete and reinsert all the tables in the database before each test. However, I am facing a problem with 4 warnings. After researching and studying this, I found recommendations to remove the **`event_loop`** from my conftest file, as pytest-asyncio provides one by default. However, when I remove the **`event_loop`**, I encounter several errors. I would like to request help in resolving these warnings.

endpoint:

```
# POST Usuario / Signup
@router.post(
    "/signup", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=UsuarioSchema
)
async def post_usuario(usuario: UsuarioSchema, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    novo_usuario: UsuarioModel = UsuarioModel(
        cpf=usuario.cpf,
        nome=usuario.nome,
        sobrenome=usuario.sobrenome,
        telefone=usuario.telefone,
        email=usuario.email,
        senha=gerar_hash_senha(usuario.senha),
        permissao_id=usuario.permissao_id,
    )
    async with db as session:
        try:
            session.add(novo_usuario)
            await session.commit()

            return novo_usuario
        except IntegrityError:
            raise HTTPException(
                detail="Dados de usuário inválidos.",
                status_code=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE,
            )
```

teste:

```
import pytest
import json
from httpx import AsyncClient
from starlette.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_201_CREATED, HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
from src.core.security import gerar_hash_senha

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ('cpf', 'nome', 'sobrenome', 'telefone', 'email', 'permissao_id', 'senha'),
    [
        (
            "12345678909",
            "NomeTesteAdmin",
            "SobrenomeTesteAdmin",
            "34912345678",
            "testeadmin@email.com",
            1,
            "290302"
        ),
        (
            "12345678910",
            "NomeTesteVendedor",
            "SobrenomeTesteVendedor",
            "34912345678",
            "testevendedor@email.com",
            2,
            "290302"
        ),
        (
            "12345678911",
            "NomeTesteCliente",
            "SobrenomeTesteCliente",
            "34912345678",
            "testecliente@email.com",
            3,
            "290302"
        )
    ]
        
)
@pytest.mark.asyncio()
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('create_database')
async def test_signup_usuario_sucesso(cpf, nome, sobrenome, telefone, email, permissao_id, senha, async_client: AsyncClient):
    payload = {
            "cpf": cpf,
            "nome": nome,
            "sobrenome": sobrenome,
            "telefone": telefone,
            "email": email,
            "permissao_id": permissao_id,
            "senha": senha
        }
    
    response = await async_client.post("/usuarios/signup", json=payload)
    data = response.json()

    assert response.status_code == HTTP_201_CREATED
    assert data['cpf'] == cpf
    assert data['nome'] == nome
    assert data['sobrenome'] == sobrenome
    assert data['telefone'] == telefone
    assert data['permissao_id'] == permissao_id
```

conftest:

```
from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator, Generator

import pytest
import asyncio
import pytest_asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient
from src.core.database import engine
from src.core.configs import settings
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from src.models.permissao_model import PermissaoModel

from src.main import app


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop() -> Generator:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
    

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='function')
async def async_client() -> AsyncGenerator:
    async_client_instance = AsyncClient(
        app=app,
        base_url="http://0.0.0.0:8000/api",
    )
    async with async_client_instance:
        yield async_client_instance


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='function')
async def create_database():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(settings.DBBaseModel.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(settings.DBBaseModel.metadata.create_all)

    async_session = sessionmaker(
        bind=create_async_engine(settings.DB_URL, echo=True),
        class_=AsyncSession,
        expire_on_commit=False
    )

    async with async_session() as session:
        permissao_admin = PermissaoModel(nome='admin')
        permissao_vendedor = PermissaoModel(nome='vendedor')
        permissao_cliente = PermissaoModel(nome='cliente')
        session.add(permissao_admin)
        session.add(permissao_vendedor)
        session.add(permissao_cliente)
        await session.commit()
```

I tried various approaches to solve the testing problem: I removed the **`event_loop`**, made changes to the **`event_loop`**, and also attempted to remove the use of **`parametrize`**. Additionally, I experimented with not deleting all the data in the database before running the tests in Pytest.